# Adding a subclass of CCSprite to a scene

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, subclass, ccsprite

I've recently decided to subclass my sprite, but I am a bit clueless on how to add them to a scene. At the moment, I have created my CCSprite subclass, using New File>Cocos2d>CCNode>Subclass of... CCSprite. Then, I have made my sprite in the Sprite.h file:

```
@interface Mos : CCSprite {
    CCSprite *mos;
}
```

Once this is done, in the Sprite.m I code this:

```
@implementation Mos

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        mos = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite_mos.png"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

What I want to know is how to then add this sprite into my game's scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to correctly subclass `CCSprite` as the [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3asprites?s=subclass#how_to_subclass_sprites) says:

```
@interface Mos : CCSprite {
    // remove the line CCSprite *mos;
}

@implementation Mos

// You probably don't need to override this method if you will not add other code inside of it
-(id) initWithTexture:(CCTexture2D*)texture rect:(CGRect)rect
{
   if( (self=[super initWithTexture:texture rect:rect]))
   {

   }
   return self;
}

+ (id)sprite
{
    return [Mos spriteWithFile:@"sprite_mos.png"];
}

@end
```

Then in your code, you can use Mos normally:

```
Mos *mos = [Mos sprite];
[scene addChild:mos];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was hoping for a way to have it so that the sprite's iamge was directly in the CCSprite subclass, as I was hoping to animate the sprite at a later date.

Comment: By the way, [scene addChild:mos]; brings up an error that says Use of undeclared indetifier "scene". Where was I meant to declare this?

Comment: @akuritsu - I modified the code, now you don't need to specify the file every time.

Comment: @akuritsu, you can modify `scene` by the actual name of your scene. I don't know what it is so I put `scene` as an example.

Comment: thought so, im just replacing it with [self adchild

Answer (score 1):

The same way you add CCSprites and other classes.

```
Mos *newMos = [[Mos alloc] init];
// set coordinates and other properties
[scene addChild:newMos];
[newMos release];
```

Edit:

```
@interface Mos : CCSprite {
    // some member variables go here
}

@implementation Mos

-(id)init
{
    CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"sprite_mos.png"];
    if( texture ) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
        rect.size = texture.contentSize;
        // set members to some values
        return [self initWithTexture:texture rect:rect];
    }
    [self release];
    return nil;
}
```

And then in your scene class

```
// ...
Mos *obj = [[Mos alloc] init];
// set position, etc
[scene addChild:obj];
[obj release];
// ...
```

Comment: and so I am guessing that I put that into my gamescene?

Comment: Yes, but you have to define the texture for your Mos object (otherwise you should add [newMos mos] as a child to the scene).

Comment: Can't I do that In my CCSprite class?

Comment: You can, of course, but not the way you have it in the class in the first post.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about doing that In my class, as that is what I want to achieve in sorts. Maybe can you post the code as an answer not comment? or just edit the current answer

Comment: I am getting an error when I run this. It is on: 

- (void) makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
 ccArrayMakeObjectsPerformSelector(data, aSelector);
}

It says: Thread 1:Program recieved Signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"